# Login Verification Android

Tags: android, json

I'm developing an android app which requires the use of a webservice to verify a user's credentials . The webpage link contains the following data :

```
{"userid":"752","success":1,"fail":0}
```

How to verify the user on the basis of this response?

Comment: Its a Json string response, convert Json object to Java Class and parse response of success attribute if its 1 then true else false.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/ 
This link might help you.

Comment: [Simple JSON parsing](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/) Go to this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to make a class for this response:

LoginDataClass.java

```
public class LoginDataClass {
    public  String userid, success, fail;
}
```

Then you have to parse this JSON and store in login data class:

```
public class DataParsingClass {
    static String Url;
    public static String Result;
    static JSONObject jsonString, subString;
    public static ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    public static void LoginData() {
        Url ="PUT YOUR LOGIN API";
        Result = HttpClass.getData(Url);

        try {

            jsonString = new JSONObject(Result);
            if (jsonString.length() > 0) {
                if (jsonString.has("userid")) {
                    LoginDataClass.userid= jsonString
                            .getString("userid");

                }
                if (jsonString.has("success")) {
                    LoginDataClass.success= jsonString
                            .getString("success");

                }
                if (jsonString.has("fail")) {
                    LoginDataClass.fail= jsonString
                            .getString("fail");

                }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Using the above, you can store your response in a class object. When you have to check if the login was successful or not, use this in your main activity where you call the login API:

```
LoginDataClass ObjLogin = new LoginDataClass();
if(ObjLogin.success.equals("1"))
{
  // write u want to do after login
}
else{
    dialog display login fail
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ishu . I accomplished the task using Basic NameValue pairs , JSON parsing , AsyncTask ( and ofcourse with the help of a friend ). It more or less has a structure matching the above code you provided

Comment: Always Welcome :) this type Of Functionality I alredy integrate in my current project and i really like json parsing.